# Can not download constraint layout in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I downloaded some project and try to run it on Android Studio, but get this error:

Error(21,13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2

I have already installed support derictory from sdk manager, but I cant see any constraint-layout folders in it. How can I solve this problem? My dependencies are:

```
   dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Comment: first Go to Sdk Manager and download constrain layout files from the extras in android studio

Comment: There's a separate pair of entries in the SDK Manager for `ConstraintLayout`. It is not distributed through the Support Repository, for some reason.

Comment: that's the problem, I dont see any constrain layout in extras

Comment: make sure your internet is working properly. and try to refresh it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Android SDK` -> `SDK Tools` and install `ConstraitLayout for Android`.

[image]

In order to open that `SDK manager` just click on the icon on the left from blue `Question mark`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I dont have any constraint-layout in my Android Support Repository ( I cant extend it as on your image) and I dont get why

Comment: Try to install things which are installed on my screenshot - `Android Support Library`, `Android SDK Tools` and so on. Im pretty sure that problem there.

Comment: What is the version of Android Studio?

Comment: I cant see Android Support Library in my SDK manager, where can I install it?

Comment: @Kate are you sure you switched to SDK tools? What version of ADS are you using?

Comment: My version is 1.5.1

Comment: @Kate ok, then first step is update to relevant version of ADS (2.3).

Comment: @Kate          Check this link, Requirement for constraintlayout : http://tools.android.com/recent/constraintlayout102isnowavailable

Comment: I'm on Studio 4 Canary and couldn't find the support repository on the sdk tools tab. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: update your ADS to the latest version and next follow the steps of Divers answer